# Best way to DRY up window resize function

Tags: jquery, function, dry

This doesn't look DRY how could I refactor this more efficiently?

```
var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
var sliderHeight = $('.slick-slider').outerHeight();
$('.slider-container').css('height', sliderHeight - headerHeight);

$(window).resize(function() {
  clearTimeout(window.resizedComplete);
  window.resizedComplete = setTimeout(function() {
    var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
    var sliderHeight = $('.slick-slider').outerHeight();
    $('.slider-container').css('height', sliderHeight -
      headerHeight);
  }, 250);
});
```

Comment: you could invoke the event outside the handler

Comment: Could you provide fiddle to an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way: Make and use a reusable function:

```
function doHeightStuff() {
    var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
    var sliderHeight = $('.slick-slider').outerHeight();
    $('.slider-container').css('height', sliderHeight - headerHeight);
}
doHeightStuff();
$(window).resize(function() {
  clearTimeout(window.resizedComplete);
  window.resizedComplete = setTimeout(doHeightStuff, 250);
});
```

Comment: Still not as DRY as I would make it, I'd store the `$('header')` etc out of the functionscope so jQuery doesn't have to select every functioncall :)

Comment: @Martijn: Sure. That's not really a DRY concern per se, more of a runtime/memory tradeoff (and of course, storing and reusuing those assumes it's the same `header`, `.slick-slider`, and `.slider-container` every time -- which seems likely but without knowing more...). Since these are only used on resize (e.g., fairly rarely), I probably wouldn't store them.